# Find x, y coordinates in two np arrays containing X and Y

Tags: python, numpy

I can't seem to find an efficient way to do this. The question is this: If I do `coords = np.where(A==0)`, where A is a numpy 2d array, I get a tuple of two np arrays, an array containing the x coordinates (of the points that satisfy the condition) and an array of y coordinates, e.g., `(array([0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3]), array([0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 3]))`. How do I know if a given point, say `(0,0)` exists in this tuple (without having to change the tuple into another structure)?

Comment: Why not ask `A[0,0] == 0`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `np.where` if you don't want the two arrays of indexes. `A==0` will return a boolean array, which may be exactly what you want, if you need to check specific indexes to see if the check is true or not.

```
mask = A==0
if mask[x,y]: # where x and y are set somewhere above...
   # do stuff
```

Of course, if the stuff you're doing is `numpy` related, checking one index at a time is likely to be less efficient than some kind of broader check that lets you do a broadcast operation. For instance, you could change *all* the `0` values in the array to `1` with this code:

```
A[mask] = 1
```

Or this, which does the equivalent of `abs` (it would be more efficient to save the mask as a separate variable, but I'm not doing that in this example to show how it's not strictly necessary):

```
A[A < 0] = -A[A < 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `argwhere` instead of `where` even if it is not optimal (read the answer of @Blccknght)

```
>>> (np.argwhere(A == 0) == [0, 0]).all(1).any()
True
```